# rewriting intersection in underscore - understanding the arguments array

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js

The function I wrote below is underscore's intersection, re written from scratch.  Right now, this works with only two arrays. how can I get this to work as is, but with an arbitrary number of arguments?

```
  _.intersection = function() {

            var argumentsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

            return _.filter(argumentsArray[0], function(val) {
                return _.indexOf(argumentsArray[1], val) != -1
            });

        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a reduce operation over the argument arrays like the following:

```
_.intersection = function() {
  var argumentsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  return _.reduce(argumentsArray, function (intersectedArray, currentArray) {
    return _.filter(intersectedArray, function(val) {
      return _.indexOf(currentArray, val) !== -1
    });
  });
};
```

Check out the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2jswLa40/).

Answer (score 1):

It's not my work 
https://jsfiddle.net/i_like_robots/KpCt2/

```
 var alpha = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        beta = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

    $.arrayIntersect = function(a, b)
    {
        return $.grep(a, function(i)
        {
            return $.inArray(i, b) > -1;
        });
    };

    window.console && console.log( $.arrayIntersect(alpha, beta) );
```

http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-set-operations.html

```
function unionArray(...arr){
    let union = new Set(arr);
    return union;
}


function Intersection(a,b){

    var a = new Set(a);
    var b = new Set(b);
    let union = new Set( [...a].filter(x => b.has(x)));
    return union;
}


function Difference(a,b)  {
    var a = new Set(a);
    var b = new Set(b);
    let union = new Set( [...a].filter(x => !b.has(x)));
    return union;
}
```